# mysql numeric database limitation

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

is there a limitation of database name can't be created as numeric?

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE 1;
```

...results in:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

....or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create databases with purely numeric names - you need to quote though:

```
CREATE DATABASE `1`;
```

Limitations on names are in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's the backticks option `whatever name`, but it's a very bad practice to use non-standard names, and even worse practice to use databases as a kind of record. Think of migrating, various automated tools, gui editors...